# Best practices on order of functs with recompose.pure and recompose.compose

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I want to compose (recompose) a React component with recompose.pure and an other hoc.
In what order should I do this ?

- compose(pure, anOtherHoc)(MyComp);
- compose(anOtherHoc, pure)(MyComp);

What is the criterion for deciding this ?

```
import { compose, pure } from "recompose";
const MyComp = ({}) => (<div>test</div>);
export default compose(pure, anOtherHoc)(MyComp);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each argument passed to the compose function creates another wrapper around the component you are enhancing.

So it really depends on `anOtherHoc` – is that a pure component, i.e. does it only have to be updated when the props that are passed to it have changed?

If yes, put `pure` first, and it will wrap `anOtherHoc`, which in turn wraps `MyComp`.

If not, put it after `anotherHoc`, then `MyComp` will wrap `pure`, which will wrap `MyComp`.

Comment: In my case, anOtherHoc is "injectIntl" from react-intl.
The state of that injectIntl may change for external reason (language changes).
So injectIntl must be before pure ?? is that right ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, I would just go ahead and test if switching languages continues to work when you wrap it in "pure"